# plot point cloud in matlab

Tags: matlab, point-clouds

I hava a point cloud, including 2,225,000 points, that the header of this codes is by format(prases in the brackets are units):

> ID,X[m],Y[m],Z[m],Range[m],Theta[deg],Phi[deg],R[0..1],G[0..1],B[0..1],Intensity[0..1]

now, i want 3D-plot this points.
I used pcshow(xyz) to plot the 2:4 columns as xyz points and i got this:
[image: 3d plot output]
Its like that points are sticked to the border!
Or, can i use the Range,Theta, phi to plot and how?

Comment: difficult to say, I would expect this to result in the intended results. How does a histogram of the Ranges look like? All/most at the same distance?

Comment: I would guess that this is what you've got in your table. What if you use plot3(x,y,y,'.'), does it give similar results?

Comment: well they are not in the same distances! so, for analyze my work, i have plotted the points with imagesc by their RGB one time, another time by Intensity instead of R and set G & B to 0 , and another , in same method this codes and plot im3. n_phi = 750 and n_Theta=3000 : `im3(:,:,3) = reshape(Range,n_phi,n_Theta);
im3(:,:,2) = reshape(Range,n_phi,n_Theta);
im3(:,:,1) = reshape(Range,n_phi,n_Theta);`